# set vmparameters in install4j based on condition

Tags: install4j

I need to set -classpath based on java version used to start the application.

In install4j -> Launchers -> Java Invocation -> VM Parameters, there is no option to specify condition. But I need to change value for the -classpath VM Parameter based on java version.

Is there any way to do so in Install4j.

Answer (score 0):

In the launcher wizard, on the "Java invocation" step, click the "Configure Version-Specific VM Parameters" button.

[image]

Comment: Thank you fr ur answer.. Btw which version of install4j does this option appears. Bcoz I didn't had this in my Install4j. Thinking I'm using older version.

Comment: You need at least install4j 6.1 for that feature